# Localization in ASP.NET Core on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to force my localization to Swedish (sv-SE). Everything is working locally, but after deploying to Azure the validation errors always show in English.

This is my configuration in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddLocalization();

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    ...

    RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
       SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("sv-SE") },
       SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("sv-SE") }
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions, new RequestCulture("sv-SE"));

    ...
}
```

When rendering the view I can see that the UI-Culture and Culture is correctly set to sv-SE both locally and on Azure.

Do I have to include something when publishing to Azure, a localization resource or something?

I'm using the latest version of ASP.NET Core (RC1).

Comment: What does your browser send as accept-language?

Comment: This is what my browser is sending:
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,sv;q=0.2. 

Even if I use the request argument ?culture=sv-SE it outputs English. It seems like the code is working, but on Azure it cant find the Swedish localization resources and outputs English instead. That is my guess at least.

Comment: The browser language shouldn't matter, because only Swedish is a supported culture. Did you deploy the Swedish resource files to Azure?

Comment: I haven't included any extra resources. Which files and where should I include them?

Comment: Are you sure you get English version or key for localized string?

Answer (score 0):

based on [this article](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/), first you need to set it up the RequestLocalizationMiddleware as a service

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    opts =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("sv-SE")
        };

        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sv-SE");
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
```

and this is not enough, the application pipeline should also be included:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)  
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    var options = 
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "default",
             template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```